# See remaining credits of iTunes account on Apple TV

Tags: itunes, appletv, itunes-store

Where can I check remaining credits of my iTunes account on my TV? I use Apple TV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's currently not possible.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1746325)​​